# Instance on Django is not working, except for picture field

Tags: django, forms, instance

Would you know why Django instance is not working properly in my code below? The idea is to allow the user to edit their articles (called seed in my code) and to do so it's more convenient for them to access the data from the current article. But for some reason, the form stays empty, except the picture field, no matter what. So I was wondering if some part of my code was canceling this instance. Thank you for any help!!

views.py

```
def seed_edit(request, slug):
    to_edit_seed = Seed.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if to_edit_seed.user.id != request.user.id:
        return render(request, 'dist/inside/knowledge/404_not_allowed.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            seed_form_edit = SeedForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=to_edit_seed)
            seed_vc_edit = SeedFormVC(request.POST)
            if seed_form_edit.is_valid() and seed_vc_edit.is_valid():
                seed = seed_form_edit.save(commit=False)
                seed.save()
                seed_form_edit.save_m2m()
                if Value_Chain_Seed.objects.filter(seed_id=to_edit_seed.id).exists():
                    f = Value_Chain_Seed.objects.filter(seed_id=to_edit_seed.id)
                    f.delete()
                    seed_vc_edit.instance.seed = to_edit_seed
                    seed_vc_edit.save()
                else:
                    seed_vc_edit.instance.seed = to_edit_seed
                    seed_vc_edit.save()
                messages.success(request,'Your seed was successfully updated!')
                return redirect(reverse(("knowledge:one_seed"),args=[to_edit_seed.slug]))
            else:
                seed_form_edit = SeedForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=to_edit_seed)
                seed_vc_edit = SeedFormVC(request.POST) 
        else:
            seed_form_edit = SeedForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=to_edit_seed)
            seed_vc_edit = SeedFormVC(request.POST)

        return render(request, 'dist/inside/knowledge/seed/edit_seed.html', {
            'to_edit_seed': to_edit_seed,
            'seed_form_edit': seed_form_edit,
            'seed_vc_edit': seed_vc_edit,
    })
```

form.py

```
class SeedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sdg = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=SDG.objects.all().exclude(id=18),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        )

    industry = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Industry.objects.all().exclude(id=10),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Seed
        fields = ["title", "profile_seed","aim_seed", "keywords"]
```

template

```
                <div class="row mx-n2">
                    <form method="post" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h5>Title - {{ seed_form_edit.title }}</h5>
                        <h5>VC - {{ seed_vc_edit.title }}</h5>
                        <hr>
                        <span><h6>Briefly summarize your seed<br><br>{{ seed_form_edit.summary }}</h6></span>
                        <span><h6>What is the aim of your seed?<br><br>{{ seed_form_edit.aim_seed }}</h6></span>
                        <span><h6>Provide maximum 4 keywords related to your seed. 
                            Please, seperate each keyword using a coma.<br><br>{{ seed_form_edit.keywords }}</h6></span> 
                        <hr>
                        <h4>Would you like to add a picture ? </h4>
                        {{ seed_form_edit.profile_seed }}
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Done</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after so long I finally understood what went wrong, in the part "else", I shouldn't add the request.Post or request.File as this stop the loading of the article.... so yeah